# how to renewed login in CAS for especial pages

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I integrated CAS with my apps that all Spring base but I need to enforce the user to re-login for accessing some of the pages for each app and after login user be redirected to requested page.How could I implement this scenario?Is it possible at all with the CAS current features? I don't want to treat this pages as a separate app.I guess maybe using renew parameter or using rest ability be helpful but I am not sure.I am using version 4.0.2 of CAS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to study the CAS protocol:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol-Specification.html

renew=true is what you may be after.